# AngularJS - Filtering out values on drop down list

Tags: json, angularjs

I've been working on my drop down list, and while I know the HTML is working fine, I can't seem to be getting the values to populate within the list correctly. I can't even seem to get into the for loop in the provided code, am I missing something?

AngularJS:

```
$scope.vendorUserList = [];
SpringDataRestService.get(
    {
        "collection": "user"
    },
    function (response) {
        var users = response;
        for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (users[i].type === "VENDOR") {
                if (users[i].status !== "PENDING_DEACTIVATION") {
                    var newUser = {id: users[i].id, name: users[i].name};
                    $scope.vendorUserList.push(newUser);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    }
);
```

JSON:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/users

{
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userName": "CLIENT 2"
}
```

Comment: Properties missing from json? Where is 'type' ?

Comment: Can't even get into the loop? So the for is just skipping? Forgive the question, but does `SpringDataRestService` return the `$http response` or `$http response.data`?

Comment: Is **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030434/4512005)** similar to what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I used AngularJS `$http.get` to *first return the entire list of users* and then I filtered out the users living in the city of Wisokyburgh that also have a zip-code, using your code (slightly modified).

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module
app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.vendorUserList = [];
  var url = root + "/users"
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      var users = data.data;
      console.log(users);
      for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].address.city === "Wisokyburgh") {
          if (users[i].address.zipcode !== "") {
            var newUser = {
              id: users[i].id,
              name: users[i].name
            };
            $scope.vendorUserList.push(newUser);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log($scope.vendorUserList);
    });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
    <select>
      <option value="0">Choose from the list</option>
      <option ng-repeat="user in vendorUserList" value="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

The case is similar to yours, but the url is public (it needs to be, so that the snippet works). Hope it helps.